# Local variables in awk functions

Tags: awk

Have been reading the gawk manual and it seems that local variables have to be defined within the argument list of the funcion declaration.

Thusly,

```
function func_name (arg,     l1,l2) {
 ...
}
```

where `l1` and `l2` would be considered as local variable, whilst all other become global variables.

Is this so?

Comment: A quick [google search](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-awk-programming/9781788391030/c70da6f1-efaa-4ac2-a68b-aa451aa1046e.xhtml): *All variables in AWK are global, except when we make variables local to function. To make a variable local to a function, we simply declare the variable as an argument after the other function arguments.*

Comment: And that means that `arg` is also a local variable. Any _other_ variable used in that function (aside from arg, l1, l2) will be global.

Comment: Is that the only way,  quite tedious for many local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example. It should be noted that the *function* will not know about global variables if these appear as arguments. But otherwise variables set inside and outside of function are the same.

```
function tt(arg, l1, l2) {
   print "Inside tt"
   print "Testing globals:   l1=",l1, "l2=",l2

   # this is not private..
   m=99
   
   # but setting these are
   l1=19
   l2=20
   
   print "global=", global
   print "arg=", arg, "l1=",l1, "l2=",l2
   print "Leaving tt"
}


BEGIN{
   arg=19     # these global variables are overruled as local by function
   l1=50      #
   l2=60      #
   global=9   # this is a different variable, so IS visible to function
   tt(1)
   print "Do we know m to be 99 ? ", m       # globally known even if set in function
   print "Do we know l1 and l2 ? ", l1, l2   # we do not know this even if set in function
}
```

Output:

```
c:\data\code\awk> awk -f testscope.awk
Inside tt
Testing globals:   l1=  l2=      # globals not seen in function
global= 9             # global not in function
arg= 1 l1= 19 l2= 20  # we use local variables here
Leaving tt
Do we know m to be 99 ?  99    # set in function
Do we know l1 and l2 ?  50 60  # global version
```

Comment: So it is true...

Answer (score 2):

All scalar (aka non-array) variables listed in the function's arg list are `'local'`.

**NOTE:** as RARE Kpop Manifesto has alluded to in comments, array processing is different; if an (global) array name is passed to the function then the function's input arg acts as a reference to the 'global' array (ie, any modifications to the reference variable will actually modify the 'global' array); on the otherhand, if a function's input arg is not associated with a passed array then that input arg will be processed as a 'local' array

Simple example of a scalar variable:

```
awk '

function print_local(x) {                  # x listed as input arg so any references in body of function are local
    x++                                    # increment is applied locally
    print "local ",x
}

function print_global() {                  # x is not listed as input arg so any references in body of function are global
    x++                                    # increment is applied globally
    print "global",x
}

BEGIN { x=9
        print "main_1",x
        print_local(x)
        print "main_2",x
        print_global()
        print "main_3",x
      }
'
```

This generates:

```
main_1 9
local  10
main_2 9
global 10
main_3 10
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `Any **scalar or non-global array** variables listed in the function's arg list are 'local'`, since passing a global array like `ARGV` as an argument and modifying it within the function would still have the changes be visible anywhere else ?

Comment: i should have clarified - arrays have their changes propagated up to locality of its original initialization style. pre-existing global arrays stay that way.  For arrays newly initialized within functions, those listed within arguments list stay local up to that point, even if that array is subsequently being passed around recursively, but those not listed in arguments list gain the global state.

Comment: Very interesting comments here. Who would have thought such a simple question could be so deep.

Answer (score 1):

there's also a difference in between `gawk/nawk` and `mawk`s — For a piece of code like this ::

```
awk '
function __(_) {

    # a dummy wrapper for built-in length()

    return length(_) 
} { 
    print __(ENVIRON), __(ARGV)
    print __(undeclared_var7)
    print    undeclared_var7 = 9 }'
```

> ```
> both gawk/nawk work fine, so numeric 9 gets assigned 
>                           into the scalar "undeclared_var7"
> ```

```
gawk
122 1
0
9

nawk
121 1
0
9
```

> ```
> mawk2 only failed the last assignment statement, 
>       and would print "121 1 0" without it
> ```

```
mawk2: line 1: illegal reference to array undeclared_var7
```

> ```
> mawk1 already failed at function call for ENVIRON since it treats all
> undeclared local vars as scalars, thus failing both ENVIRON and ARGV
> ```

```
mawk1: line 1: type error in arg(1) in call to __
mawk1: line 1: type error in arg(1) in call to __

to partially remedy it, modify it to

     mawk1 'function __(_,___) {
                for (___ in _) { break } 
                return length(_) 
            }
            BEGIN { print __(ENVIRON) }'    
     121
```

> ```
> it's partial because now "undeclared_var7" got initialized as an
> array by the function, so the assignment of 9 would now fail instead.
> ```

side note : `gawk` somehow sees 1 extra item consistently at `ENVIRON` compared to any other `awk`